# algorithm for calculating the nth root of a number from Wikipedia

Tags: c

What's wrong with the bit of code below?
I'm trying to write a program to calculate the nth root of a number but the output for the calculation I'm writing keeps coming back as 0. I simply put the numbers in to see if I would get a result of the calculation and assign it to ans2 but only a 0 gets assigned.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

    int n = 2;
    double A = 4.0, ans = 1.0, ans2 = 1.0, pow = 1.0;

    ans2 = (1/n)*((n-1)*ans+(A/pow));

    printf("\n%lf\n", ans2);
    printf("\n%lf\n", ans);
    printf("\n%lf\n", pow);
    printf("\n%lf\n", A);
    printf("\n%d\n", n);
}
```

Comment: `(1/n)` => (1/2) => (0). use `double` instead of `int` or `(1.0/n)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to either:

1. Write the `ans2` equation as `ans2 = (1.0/n)*((n-1.0)*ans+(A/pow));`
2. Declare `n` as a double.

With the way you have it written, the compiler will interpret `1/n` as a signed integer. In integer form, `1` is just:

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

So when you divide it by any positive integer `n > 1`, it will just right shift that least significant bit off of the end, causing the result to get truncated to 0.

Comment: Also, it's better practice to main `main` return an `int` rather than void as a process should usually return an exit status.